# App stuck in splash screen in IOS after using react-native-splash-screen

Tags: ios, react-native, splash-screen

When I am using the react-native-splash-screnn the ios app is stuck at the splash screen. I just attached the my app.js file and also the delegat.m file for ios

This is my app.js file

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Navigations from './src/Routes/Navigations';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const ac = new AbortController();
    setTimeout(() => {
      SplashScreen.hide();
    }, 1000);
    return function cleanup() {
      ac.abort();
    };
  }, [])
  return (
    <Navigations />
  );
}
export default App;
```

And there is my Appdelegate.m file for IOS

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import "RNSplashScreen.h"
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

  self.moduleName = @"spengucomputer";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};
  [RNSplashScreen show];
  [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

Please help me to resolve the issue because I'm new to IOS.

Comment: Do you mean stuck or just blank screen instead of logo or image?

Comment: Splash screen hide not working, just stuck

Comment: Did you got it resolved!